# how to change HTTP Request URL using angular 6 interceptor

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I am working on a angular app & fetching data from back end API endpoint with the get / post method of HTTP module.
Recently I have checked a angular app where they are hiding API real endpoint & replacing with some other end point.

for e.g

Real Endpoint:- 'http://192.168.1.192:8080/restaurant/getUserData/'

Replaced Endpoint:- 'http://192.168.1.192:8080/restaurant/getServerData'

also I can see the replaced endpoint in the 'network' tab of 'Developer Tool'.

I know that this can be achieved by using interceptors concept. but I never worked with HTTP interceptor. 
if any one know how to achieve the same please suggest.

Comment: Please refer to https://angular.io/guide/http#http-interceptors

Comment: http interceptors are not used for this purpose generally.

Comment: I would suggest you look at proxy https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 4):

```
@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 constructor() { }
 const redirectRequest = request.clone({ url: 'http://192.168.1.192:8080/restaurant/getServerData', method: "get" });
      return next.handle(redirectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const dupReq = req.clone({ url: 'mynewurl.com' });
    return next.handle(dupReq);
  }
}
```